# How to make command line tool work in windows and linux?

Tags: command-line

Making my PHP Command line application support Linux and Windows.  Currently it has this code below to work from command line on Linux/unix

How can I make it work on Windows?  I lan on having a setting to determine if the sytem is Linux or Windows and using the correct commands based on that but I do not know how to make these function below work in Windows

`exec()` is a PHP function to run stuff through the command line

```
exec("rm -f $dest_file", $var);

exec("mv $quant_file {$this->tmp_path}/{$src_filename}-quant.png");
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the PHP versions of these commands? Just curious...

Comment: @Lior Cohen i'm not sure it's a project maintained by someone else

Comment: Check out: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

Comment: @Lior Cohen  I should of mentioned, the rest of the project uses the exec() extensively to run other command line tools so thats probably why, but I reckon the php commands should work as well since I have the path saved in a variable

Comment: ah, gotcha. Revised my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test which platform you're on using the PHP_OS constant and run commands accordingly.

I would, however, suggest that you use the PHP provided filesystem functions (if possible).

Here are some links:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.dir.php